# Reversing a Linked List recursive solution problem

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I have written the following code for reversing a linked list through recursion. However, it didn't work and when I debugged it I could see that the changes in each of the calls weren't being passed to the calls beneath it in the stack. For example, lets say we have linked list 1->2->null. The calls made will be reverse(null,1,null),reverse(1,2,null),then finally reverse(2,null,null). At the final call, as per my code new head should be changed to point at 2 which will then be constant throughout the rest of the stack calls since, I am sending in the reference of newHead to reverse. However, when this call is exited from the stack, then newHead goes back to being null in the previous call which is reverse(1,2,newHead:null). Not sure why this is happening. Can someone please explain to me why this is happening. I am really confused.

Thank you!!

```
public class ListNode {
 int val;
  ListNode next;
  ListNode() {}
  ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 
 public static ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
    if(head==null){
        return null;
    }
        ListNode newHead = head;
        reverse(null,head,newHead);
        return newHead;
        
    }
    
    private static void reverse(ListNode prev, ListNode curr, ListNode newHead){
        if(curr==null){
            newHead = prev;
            return;
        }
        reverse(curr,curr.next,newHead);
        curr.next = prev;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode head = new ListNode(1,new ListNode(2));
        reverseList(head);
        System.out.print(head.val);
    }
```

}

Comment: Wait, so what exactly happens when you pass in an object or an array etc?

Comment: yeah, but if a copy of their reference (which is the memory address) is passed in, won't it change the content? I don't understand

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite understanding what you are trying to say. When you pass in an object reference by value, won't it still point to the same object in the heap? so this will change the content right?

Comment: The *variable* `newHead` is local. Assigning to it does not influence the caller's variables. However, *mutating* it, with like `newHead.next = ...` *would* affect the single object that both the caller and the local variable reference.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a *variable* as argument to a function, like with `reverse(head)`, you cannot expect that function to change the variable's *value*. `head` will still reference the *same* node after the call. The only thing you can expect from this, is that the function will mutate that node and adjust its `next` property (or any other property), but it cannot make `head` reference a *different* node.

When in `reverse` you assign like `newHead = prev;` that will only affect the value of `newHead`, which is a local variable. If you would do `newHead.next = null`, then yes, the property will change in that *object*, to which also the caller has access via their own variable. But that is *mutation*, while in your code you are not mutating, but assigning to a variable.

So make `reverse` *return* the new value, and let the caller capture that and assign it to their local variable, ...etc.

```
    public static ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        if (head == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ListNode newHead = head;
        return reverse(null, head, newHead); // <-- return it
    }
    
    private static ListNode reverse(ListNode prev, ListNode curr, ListNode newHead) {
        if (curr == null) {
            return prev; // <-- return it
        }
        // Capture the returned node reference
        newHead = reverse(curr, curr.next, newHead);
        curr.next = prev;
        return newHead; // <--- and bubble it up the recursive chain
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode head = new ListNode(1, new ListNode(2));
        head = reverseList(head);
        System.out.println(head.val); // 2
    }
```